# consuming the web api in angular project

Tags: angular

I am consuming a web api cors, its type of action is GET.
I want to get the result of the web api in a public property in the angular project.
My problem that the property in which the result is affected is still `null` it returns an undefined value.
This is the code of the service method:

```
/**********Operation.service.ts**************/

 public  GetXmlDefinition():any
{
  debugger;
  console.log("Response before : "+this.resultXmlDefinition)
 return this.http.get('https://localhost:44388/api/XmlFile/GetXmlContent/');
  /*.subscribe(response=>{  

    this.resultXmlDefinition=response; console.log("Response After : "+this.resultXmlDefinition);});
    console.log("Response final : "+this.resultXmlDefinition);*/
   //return this.resultXmlDefinition;   
}
```

The code in the component.ts:

```
public operation: OperationsService;
 public xmlDoc:string="";
  constructor( private gridcolumns:OperationsService) {
    this.operation=gridcolumns;
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.operation.GetXmlDefinition().subscribe(function(data){this.xmlDoc=data.toString();})
}
```

The value of `this.xmlDoc` is undefined after execution

Answer (score 0):

In a callback function 'this' is not necessarily what you want it to be. Try

```
ngOnInit() {
  let self = this;
  self.operation.GetXmlDefinition().subscribe(
    data => {
      self.xmlDoc=data.toString();
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: i tired this but i get the same result undefined

Answer (score 0):

You should learn angular component lifecycle. Your "GetXmlDefinition()" is asynchronous. When the component initialized your "xmlDoc" property is undefined. If you want to have "xmldoc" value when the component is ready you should use router resolvers.

[Angular Router Resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)